# Webdriver Issues With Firefox V2.50.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML for one of the month dropdown in application under test.

```
<div class="dd ddcommon form-control respstyled-select-monthAC ng-isolate-scope borderRadius" id="month2_msdd" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 1;">
    <div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff" id="month2_arrow"></span>
        <span class="ddTitleText "  id="month2_title"><span class="ddlabel">month</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span></div><input type="text" id="month2_titleText" autocomplete="off" class="text shadow borderRadius" style="display: none;">
    <div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="month2_child" style="z-index: 1; display: none; position: absolute; max-height: 288px; top: 28px;">
        <ul><li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><span class="ddlabel">month</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span          class="ddlabel">January</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">February</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">March</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">April</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">May</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">June</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">July</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">August</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">September</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">October</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">November</span><div class="clear"></div></li>
            <li class="enabled _msddli_"><span class="ddlabel">December</span><div class="clear"></div></li></ul></div></div>
```

I used the following script to select January option from the dropdown:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id="month2_arrow"])).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='month2_child']/ul/li[2]/span)).click();
```

This code will have two clicks to select January option from the month dropdown.This was working fine till Selenium Webdriver 2.47. When I upgraded the selenium to 2.50, both the steps are executed successfully but the option is not selected.

Comment: Can you post error-log?

Comment: There is no error. It says it clicked on the option but it will not select in month dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is providing an interface as `javascriptexecutor`.

You can do it something like below:-

```
      WebElement element= driver.findElement("YOUR Locator"));
      JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This worked out. Thanks. But why there is behavioral between various versions of selenium? Why normal click not working?

Comment: Selenium API is made accoding to browser version compatibility suppose today firefox have 44 version and our latest jars supporting it .. now in future mozilla will made some changes then selenium also need to rewrite different API's call according to same .. That's why these difference occurs .. there are some known issue also present which they are resolving time to time and pushed as new version of selenium thts also sometimes shows different behaviours with new jars

Comment: There is some issue facing by all over the world .. look into it you will have a better idea .. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1202.....  Please accept the answer if it really helps you and feel free to vote up ... it will really help :) ... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update . I tried to vote up . But this message is thrown 'Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score'

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach would be giving focus to the dropdown and then using sendKeys() method to type the name of the month that you want. This will select the month and sending an Enter via sendKeys() will confirm your selection.

Comment: Thanks. This works out. But this will be tedious task to change the script in all the places. Why this issue is happening with latest versions of Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can download firefox ESR. Its stable version of firefox.
Current supported official releases is Firefox 38.6.0 ESR and is compatibile with latest Selenium Webdriver.